# O1RA-0229 integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints

SQL Database code:

```
CREATE TABLE MYBUILDING 
(
B_NUMBER NUMBER(1)      NOT NULL, 
NAME VARCHAR2(25)       NOT NULL, 
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(40)        NOT NULL, 
P_CODE VARCHAR2(6) , 
FLOOR_NUM_UP NUMBER(3)      DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL CHECK (FLOOR_NUM_UP >= 0), 
FLOOR_NUM_DOWN NUMBER(3)    DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL CHECK (FLOOR_NUM_DOWN >= 0), 
CONS_DATE DATE          NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (B_NUMBER)
); 
-------
CREATE TABLE FLOOR
(
B_NUMBER NUMBER(1)      NOT NULL,
F_NUMBER NUMBER(2)      NOT NULL CHECK (F_NUMBER >= -4 AND F_NUMBER <= 25),
SPACE_M NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL CHECK (SPACE_M > 0), 
PRIMARY KEY (B_NUMBER, F_NUMBER), 
FOREIGN KEY (B_NUMBER) REFERENCES MYBUILDING
); 
------
CREATE TABLE TENANT 
(
TENANT_NUM NUMBER(3)        NOT NULL,
TENANT_NAME VARCHAR2(40)    NOT NULL,
C_NAME VARCHAR2(40)     NOT NULL,
C_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(40),
P_CODE  VARCHAR2(6),
P_NUMBER NUMBER(12),
PRIMARY KEY (TENANT_NUM)
);        
-------
CREATE TABLE LOCATION
(
B_NUMBER NUMBER(1)      NOT NULL,
F_NUMBER NUMBER(2)      NOT NULL,
L_NUMBER NUMBER(3)      NOT NULL CHECK (L_NUMBER > 0 AND L_NUMBER < 100 ), 
SPACE_M NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL, 
RATE NUMBER(5)          NOT NULL CHECK (RATE >= 0 AND RATE <= 350), 
RENT NUMBER(4)          NOT NULL, 
S_DATE DATE, 
E_DATE DATE,
TENANT_NUM NUMBER(3),
PRIMARY KEY (L_NUMBER, F_NUMBER, TENANT_NUM),
CONSTRAINT FK_TENANT FOREIGN KEY (TENANT_NUM) REFERENCES TENANT ON DELETE SET NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (B_NUMBER, F_NUMBER) REFERENCES FLOOR 
);
```

Hello Everyone! I made a series of tables and i think i did everything correct. i entered my input values on all the tables without a hitch except for the LOCATION table.

this is the Error thats giving me.

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (1, 1, 1, 300, 101, 0, '01-JAN-2004', '30-JUN-2004', 1);
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (1, 1, 1, 300, 101, 0, '01-JAN-2004', '30-JUN-2004', 1)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ASSIGNMENT.FK_TENANT) violated - parent key
>   not found.

Any help and tips will be appreciated. THanks!

fixed.

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION(

B_NUMBER NUMBER(1)      NOT NULL,

F_NUMBER NUMBER(2)      NOT NULL,

L_NUMBER NUMBER(3)      NOT NULL CHECK (L_NUMBER > 0 AND L_NUMBER < 100 ), 

SPACE_M NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL, 


RATE NUMBER(5)          NOT NULL CHECK (RATE >= 0 AND RATE <= 350), 

RENT NUMBER(4)          NOT NULL, 

S_DATE DATE, 

E_DATE DATE,

TENANT_NUM NUMBER(3)        NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (L_NUMBER, B_NUMBER, F_NUMBER, TENANT_NUM),

FOREIGN KEY (TENANT_NUM) REFERENCES TENANT ON DELETE SET NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (B_NUMBER, F_NUMBER) REFERENCES FLOOR 

);
```

Comment: So .. what's the question? (The tags, title and error message seem to cover everything.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your insert statement is trying to insert a value into column TENANT_NUM which doesn't exist in the TENANT table - (There's a foreign key constraint on the Location table).

Comment: that made perfect sense.... thank you! everything works fine now! i would also like to ask if, is it possible to input a null value on TENANT_NUM under the LOCATION table?

Comment: TENANT_NUM is part of the primary key for that table so the answer is no.